# How to know which tableview cell's text field is changed its content

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a tableview with around 100 text fields inside it. I added only one text field. It is reused and it is accessed using tag.

The problem is this: suppose the user has changed some textfield.  Now, I want to access that text field changes during saving of the data.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very near to your goal. You have already assigned tag to your `UITextField`. You can use and track tag in this delegate method.

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First set tag of textfield  with indexpath.row

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
  {
 // replace text in your array
  }
```